# Share Sessions Between Zend and Pure PHP on Same Domain

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

I have two folder like this:

1. /public/zend_app/
2. /public/pure_php/

And Drupal has been installed in root.

Now, I want to create a session in second path and use it in zend.
I tried some different ways to do it but failure was the resut!

I check **session_id** and **session_save_path** for both which are same now.

In second folder I have this:

```
session_start();
session_id($_COOKIE[PHPSESSID]);
$_SESSION[user] = 123;
```

And in first one:

```
$someNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('ns');
//......

session_id($_COOKIE[PHPSESSID]);
print_r($_SESSION);
```

But it returns empty array!

Also I tried this in second folder:

```
set_include_path ( $zend_path );
include_once $zend_path . '/Session.php';
$user = new Zend_Session_Namespace('user');
```

But I get this error: (I can't prevent running session_start to escape this error)

> Zend_Session_Exception: session has already been started by
>   session.auto-start or session_start() in Zend_Session::start() (line
>   462 of C:\wamp\www\zend_app\library\Zend\Session.php).

Now my question is that how can I share it with zend? 
Does Zend use special handler? How can I use it in pure php code?

Comment: Remove the `session_id` calls, they shouldn't be there. Also your array indexes should be quoted, e.g. `$_SESSION['user']`. I would suggest checking whether the session file actually has anything in it after visiting your PHP app.

Comment: I checked it, not working. It returns different value when I try "echo session_id();"

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html

```
$myNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('myNamespace');

// $myNamespace corresponds to $_SESSION['myNamespace']
```

Get rid of `session_id()`, you don't need to give PHP the cookie, that's handled automatically.

I just tried this in a ZF controller:

```
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('ns');
$session->foo = "bar";
print_r($_SESSION);
```

And this is what I got out:

```
Array
(
        [ns] => Array
        (
            [foo] => bar
        )
}
```

So I can access `$_SESSION['ns']['foo']` now in pure PHP. I can also set values in pure PHP:

```
$_SESSION['ns']['baz'] = "quz";
```

And later access in ZF:

```
echo $session->baz; // gives me "quz"
```

Comment: You'll also need to make sure the [session name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) is the same as [configured in the ZF app](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.global_session_management.html#zend.session.global_session_management.configuration_options)

Comment: I want vice versa, however this code do not work for me and I think the problem may cause by drupal cms which is installed in root...